# Sending an email/message/notification to user on user entered future date

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and iOS app development. I am trying to develop an app where a user enters a future date. And the app automatically sends a message/email/notification to the user phone 2 days prior to the date entered by the user.

For example : a user enters Exam Due Date as February 6, 2016. So the app send a message/email/notification to user phone on February 4, 2016 automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UILocalNotification` with a `fireDate` in the future

Comment: Thanks. I used the UILocalNotification and firedate as below and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

func sendNotification(dueDate:String)

```
{
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let dateAsString = dueDate
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    let newDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString)
    let notification : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertTitle = "Alert"
    notification.alertBody = "Alert body. Thank You!"
    notification.fireDate = newDate
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

}
```